# Wrapping a single value for more explicit method parameter declaration

Tags: java, coding-style

I just asked myself if it's good to wrap a single e.g. String in a class, just to get a more explicit method signature.

```
public final class Auftragsnummer {

    private final String value; 

    public Auftragsnummer(String value) { this.value = value; }

    public String value() { return value; }

}
```

I came up with it, because I often interchanged my parameters accidentally.

Comment: It depends - it may be worth it if an `Auftragsnummer` needs to adhere to a certain format, or if it helps you to  express some domain specific logic, if this is part of an effort to define a [Ubiquitous Language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202597/ubiquitous-language-and-custom-types).  But I fear as is, you question is too broad to be answered in general.

Comment: Very related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/281827/should-we-define-types-for-everything

Answer (score 1):

If you have an enclosing class, e.g. `Auftrag` which then has an `AuftragsNummer`:

```
public class Auftrag {
    private AuftragsNummer nummer;
}
```

then I would say it doesn't really make sense. Because said `auftragsNummer` is always just used within the context of `Auftrag` so it can just be a `String`.

---

If you don't have an enclosing class, e.g. `AuftragsNummer` is passed around "alone". Then it may be preferred.

---

> I came up with it, because I often interchanged my parameters accidentally.

An easy way to not mix up parameters is to give them meaningful names. Calling a `String` variable e.g. `string` is discouraged and so on, just name that variable `auftragsNummer`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you are basically saying the detail of the type of object that the string will contain in terms of explaining it through code. But for this purpose you can just use a string and name it with a particular name, in this case `String auftragsnummer;` (I don't know the meaning of the word btw).

Comment: Auftrag is german and stands for Job / Order, depending on the context, and Nummer is Number :)

Comment: @Lino Thanks, it still applies to any context though. :)